# Is inertial mass actually reverse-time gravity reaching back from the distant future and pushing?

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime

[**James Woodward of Cal State Fullerton says so**](https://physics.fullerton.edu/%7Ejimw/general/inertia/index.htm). He say it's just like an advanced wave in QED. He says that  gravity accounts for inertial reaction forces as long as the interaction of local stuff with the gravity field of distant matter is like the interaction of electric charges and currents with the electromagnetic field.

My question is: *is this correct?*

Answer (score 2):

Regardless of the validity of Woodward hypothesis (which might or might not been experimentally refuted already), for his argument to work in order to provide an inertia-like contribution to mass, he is relying on the fact that cosmological sources of mass are mostly positive, and their net rough contribution is:

$$\phi_g = \frac{GM}{R}$$

with $M$ and $R$ being the mass and observable radius of the universe. This is obviously a field contribution coming from the past light cone of the test mass, hence there is no "future" weird contributions going on here.

His hypothesis relies on pushing the analogy between electromagnetism and gravity, using the gravitational version of the Lienard-Wiechert potential equations for charged sources, specifically

$$ \mathbf{A_g} = \frac{1}{c} \int \frac{\rho \mathbf{v}}{r} dV $$

This is again, integrated over the past lightcone, which includes all cosmological mass sources.

Now, the most likely error in his argument, is when they take the velocity out of the volume integral, and just equate the vector potential with the velocity times the potential:

$$ \mathbf{A_g} \propto \phi_g \mathbf{v} $$

In fact I would argue that if you do this integration correctly, since most cosmological mass in the integral is moving away isotropically from the test mass, then the integral should mostly cancel out, and the only net contribution should rely on anisotropic mass distribution

But pursuing his line of reasoning a little bit further, they use the gravitational version of the electric field force equation as the equivalent of Newton's law of motion:

$$ E_g = -\nabla{\phi_g} - \frac{1}{c}\frac{\partial \mathbf{A_g}}{\partial t}$$

$$ E_g \propto \frac{\phi_g}{c^2} \frac{d\mathbf{v}}{dt} $$

This last follows from the "cosmological source potential" $\phi$, which has no spatial gradient by itself, and the (questionable) simplification of taking $\mathbf{v}$ from the sources of $\mathbf{A}$

Regarding the validity of his hypothesis: He continues to infer certain ways to create "transient" variations of inertia, he proposed piezoelectric experimental rigs well over 4 decades ago, and if it would have produced any interesting results, it would have been already published. Unfortunately when people become emotionally involved with their pet theories, they keep grooming them even long after they are functionally dead, never acknowledging the stench